# Is there a way to visualize / print out which templates were used to render a given piece of UI?

Tags: theme-development

Trying to customize Twenty Elevent theme it would be super useful for me as a beginner to see which templates rendered which pages / parts of the pages. Is there a plugin or manual way to achieve that? The easiest thing that comes to mind would be to add HTML comments to each and every template file but maybe some plugin / procedure automates this task already?

Comment: As in to tell the difference between what was done by header.php and index.php?

Comment: Yes, like from which file came the header (most probably `header.php`), where did sidebar come from etc. If I'm correct the "template" in Wordpress usually means only the single resulting file like `page.php`, `single.php` or `404.php` but those files are usually composed from many more *.php files, e.g. Twenty Eleven has about 20 of them like `content-page.php`, `tag.php` and I'd like to visualize how those work together to build the resulting page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something i use when developing themes:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'store_template_file', 999 );
function store_template_file( $template ){
    $GLOBALS['current_theme_file'] = basename($template);
    return $template;
}

add_action('wp_footer','print_theme_file');
function print_theme_file(){
    if( !isset( $GLOBALS['current_theme_file'] ) || is_admin() )
        return;
    echo '<!-- Current theme file: ' .  $GLOBALS['current_theme_file'] . '-->';
}
```

Once you paste that in your theme's functions.php file it will print out an HTML comment at the footer with the theme file's name.

Comment: Usefull as well but am I correct that this will print out only the "target" template file and not how the page was constructed, i.e. where sidebar came from, where navigation came from etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable debugging and install the debug bar, it won't tell you which specific areas of a template are used , but there is a lot of useful data including which actual template page is being called.

In wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true); //scripts
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);  //SQL
```

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/

[image]

Comment: This is useful but if there's any way to display more in-depth information about how the page is composed from templates like header, footer, sidebar etc. it would great.

Comment: What you're asking for does not really relate to WordPress, you would need to install something like Xdebug and a proper IDE that can step through PHP code.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to step through PHP code, it's just that when I look at e.g. `index.php` which the debug bar suggests is the template used for the current page, there are many more files involved, e.g. `header.php`, `footer.php`, maybe things like `content-page.php`? I don't know how to tell which files are cooperating on rendering the resulting page. I hope there is an easier way than using xdebug.

Comment: Looking at the Twenty Eleven files a bit more, it seems that some files are **"templates"**, like they can appear in the "Query template" field of the Debug Bar like in the screenshot you posted (those are files like `index.php`, `404.php`, `archive.php` etc.) and then some files are **"template parts"** - they provide pieces of HTML to the real templates. Examples of these files would be `header.php`, `footer.php`, `comments.php` etc. This distinctions is something I have observed, not read about, is it about right? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: yes, there nothing that will tell you the specifics besides proper debugging or actual know-how, I suggest the latter by reading the codex, for example http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part and http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy and http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development , but every theme is different

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using firebug?

Maybe also checkout: http://yoast.com/wordpress-theme-anatomy/

Comment: How will Firebug help me find out which server-side file rendered a part of a page? But the link seems useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't specifically answer your question... but... If you're jumping into theme / plugin development I'd highly recommend [Digging Into WordPress](http://digwp.com/) by Chris Coyier & Jeff Starr.  There's a really great chapter named "Understanding Theme Files" that breaks down and explains what these files are used for, and how to get the most out of best practices.

I don't have any affiliation with them, except that their book really jumpstarted my ability to build themes and plugins. It's one of those rare books that is super easy to follow as a beginner but also remains very useful as an experienced developer.